# filter with dates in reports

Tags: python, odoo

I have a report that works perfectly for me but they ask me that before I launch the results it will be filtered through a start date and end date set before entering the report, someone knows how I can perform that process of having a view to select the start date and end date to add it to a report that is already working but that filter is required?

I want to show the items that are in a date range that that date is previously selected. For example: Pono start date: 01/01/2019 and end date: 01/30/2019 when you enter those dates will show the elements that are only in that range.

searching online I found this code:

```
  **filter name = "today" string = "Today"
  domain = "[('date', '> =', datetime.datetime.combine (context_today (), 
  datetime.time (0,0,0))),
  ('date', '<=', datetime.datetime.combine (context_today (), 
  datetime.time (23,59,59)))] "/>**
```

Now my question, I want to enter it in my view of the report but I don't know how to put it, could you help me and change today to make it monthly?

Small excerpt from my report view:

```
    <report
        id = "larger_list"
        model = "project_rc.account"
        string = "Lmayor"
        name = "project_rc.report_cuenta_view"
        file = "project_rc.report_lmayor"
        report_type = "qweb-html" />

    <template id = "report_cuenta_view">
        <t t-call = "web.html_container">
            <t t-foreach = "docs" t-as = "i">
                <t t-call = "web.internal_layout">
                    <div class = "page">
```

h2 style = "text-align: center"> Ledger

```
                        <h3> Account

                            <span t-esc = "i.title" />

                        </h3>

                        <table class = "table">

                            <tr>

                                <th style = "text-align: center"> Date </th>

                                <th style = "text-align: center"> Corporate name </th>
                                <th style = "text-align: center"> Must </th>

                                <th style = "text-align: center"> credit </th>

                                </tr>

                            <t t-foreach = "i.detalle_documento_ids" t-as = "or">

                                <tr>

                                    <td>

                                        <span t-esc = "o.date" />

                                    </td>

                                    <td>

                                        <span t-esc = "o.corporate_name_id.name" />

                                    </td>

                                    <td>

                                        <span t-esc = "o.total_must" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span t-esc = "o.total_credit" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </t>
```

The report is associated with the table called "Account", but it has a foreign key with the table "document_detail" which is where the date I want to filter is taken.

**class Account (models.Model):**

```
  _name = 'project_rc.account'

  _rec_name = 'title'

  title = fields.Char (string = "Name")

  document_document_ids = fields.One2many (as del_name = 'project_rc.detail_document', inverse_name = 'account_id', string = 'Document detail',
      required = True)
```

**class Document_Detail (models.Model):**

```
  _name = 'project_rc.detail_document'

  _rec_name = 'date'

  date = fields.Date (string = "Date", related = 'document_id.date')
```

.
.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example to reproduce the problem. Thank you!

Comment: thanks, I just gave an example, I hope it is understood and you can collaborate

Comment: Are you using a wizard to select this dates? and how are you calling the report actions?

Comment: In the past I was using wizard but I stopped using it because there is no way to make it work so I made it as a simple report but I just need to put a date filter.

Comment: please provide the report file also

Comment: I just added code that I used to make the report and the tables that are involved.